# How to show changes made by one instance of Windows application on other instances of application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, distributed-computing

Here is my scenario:

I have to develop a WPF application in C#.NET that has two main users: a Team Lead (TL) and an Operating Technician (OT). This application will be running on multiple separate machines on the same network. The application will be used by the Operating Technician to view a list of Job Numbers and the Team Lead will be able to update the list of Job Numbers as needed.

My problem is that I am not sure how to display those changes to the Operating Technician after the Team Lead has made them.

There will be unique instances of the application running on both the OT's and the the TL's machines.

My first thought was to have the TL's instance update a database and have the OT's instance be periodically checking the database for updates, but this seems clunky and a poor design.

Is there a way that once the TL updates the list of Job Numbers, I can send a "trigger" over the network to the OT's instance to tell it to update?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a TCP listening service on the Operating Technician's machine, and a TCP client on the Team Lead's machine
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2418/Making-Socket-Based-Application-Using-TcpListener

Answer (score 0):

You can host WCF service inside your WPF application (like [described](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/11/01/wcf-service-hosting-how-to-host-a-wcf-service-from-inside-a-windows-presentation-foundation-application/) here for example). That service will run on some port on your OT machine and will listen for incoming events from TL machine (which should know address and port of OT machine). Of course database is still needed to share data, but this database need not to be polled.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to use some sort of a message bus, e.g. RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ, in a publish/subscribe pattern.
OT's instances will subscribe to a topic, and TL's instance will publish updates with job numbers on it.

Answer (score 0):

why you not use database events to notify the clients about a database update.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189453.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to try out using MQTT protocol to offer a pub/sub service for the different applications. This will solve a few things with the problem as there are actually multiple Team Leads who will each have their own Operating Technician.

Now to find out how to implement MQTT with .NET.

Anyone?